# How is the default hostname set in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, system-installation, hardware

How is the default hostname set? Usually it is something akin to the manufacturers model name or string. I am curious how that value is accessed, as it seems it would be something from the bios or hardware level response. Like "HP-Smartbook-20020" or something like this. Is there a command I can run in Linux to generate that string output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`hostnamectl`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/hostnamectl.1.html) will output information used in generation of a hostname. Source is [here](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/main/src/hostname/hostnamectl.c) in case you're interested in how the values are sourced (uses bus_map_all_properties, which probably pulls from `/proc`).

Comment: Ah thanks! I followed that trail and it uses BIOS info from dmidecode type resources.